# Where has thre ALSA tab gone in my QJackdctl?

Tags: sound, alsa, jack, midi

I have no ALSA tab anymore in my QJackdctl.

I am trying with copious amounts of failure to get output from my midi keyboard on Ubuntu. After playing around a bit (clicking a few options, following various tutorials on Midi and Ubuntu)the Alsa tab has disappeared.
In the advanced tab of QJackdctl the driver is "alsa".
This thread suggests that that that was the problem:
https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=24585

Any ideas? It's not like it was working before but this seems to be a step backward.

Comment: It says to enable alsa sequencer support. Is that option checked?

Comment: Also, this is just a guess but did you install `a2jmidid` and `multimedia-jack`? `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install a2jmidid multimedia-jack`

Comment: Brilliant. Now it's back.
Now I'm back to the stage of having midi input but no output. If you know how to solve that I'd jump for joy!

Answer (score 0):

It says to enable alsa sequencer support. Is that option checked?

[image]

Also, a quick search using `apt-cache search` suggests that you may need the following packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install a2jmidid multimedia-jack
```

Example search:

```
apt-cache search jack
```

and you can filter results using `grep` to only include results that contain "midi":

```
apt-cache search jack | grep -i alsa
```

the `-i` option disables case sensitivity.

---

[Image source and referenced thread on linuxmusicians.com](https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=24585)